Iterating over each dataframe in a list of dataframes and changing name of first column
I'm trying to iterate through a list of datraframes and do two things, replace blanks with "_" (which I've done) and add a suffix to the first column of each dataframe. I know I can access the first column of the each dataframe via the print row within the loop below, but I'm having trouble adding the suffix to the first column. Can someone please help?
Sample data:
import pandas as pd

px_data = {'Date': ['8/11/18', '8/12/18', '8/13/18', '8/14/18'],
        'A df': [58.63, 21.25, 19.17, 18.8],
        'B df': [35,105,27,98]}

SC_data = {'Date': ['8/11/18', '8/12/18', '8/13/18', '8/14/18'],
        'A df': [20.50, 6, 82, 74.6],
        'B df': [74,62,8,99]}

SMA_data = {'Date': ['8/11/18', '8/12/18', '8/13/18', '8/14/18'],
        'A df': [2, 95.3, 39, 68.27],
        'B df': [58,37,74,11]}

px = pd.DataFrame(px_data)
SC = pd.DataFrame(SC_data)
SMA = pd.DataFrame(SMA_data)

dfs=[px,SC,SMA]
   
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i].columns = dfs[i].columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
    print(dfs[i].columns[0])


Why do you not concat them?

Because this is part of a larger piece of code and the idea is to make some simple adjustments within the list of dataframes itself prior to splitting up the list into multiple dataframes.

After replacing blanks with underscore, you can add suffix to the first columns of each dataframe in the following way:
first_column = dfs[i].columns[0] # get first column
dfs[i].rename(columns={first_column: first_column + '_suffix'}, inplace=True) # Add a suffix to the first column


Thank you, this is perfect for my application. Much appreciated.

A possible solution, which uses list comprehension to recreate the column names:
for df in [px, SC, SMA]:
    df.columns = [
        'Date_suf' if i == 0 else x.replace(' ', '_')
        for i, x in enumerate(df.columns)]

Or even better, as @iBeMeltin suggests in a comment below and to whom I thank:
for df in [px, SC, SMA]:
    df.columns = [
        x + '_suffix' if i == 0 else x.replace(' ', '_')
        for i, x in enumerate(df.columns)]


Thanks! I probably should have mentioned that I can't have anything hard coded, so the idea is to just take the first column in each dataframe within the list, and add a suffix to it. Effectively the column name plus some string would do the trick, but I can't seem to make that happen.

Could you please elaborate a bit more, as it is not very clear to me what you really need.

The following also works fine: `dfs = [px, SC, SMA]
for k in range(len(dfs)):
dfs[k].columns = [
'Date_suf' if i == 0 else x.replace(' ', '_')
for i, x in enumerate(df.columns)]
dfs`.

Yes, I think that would work for me too, thank you!

you could just replace 'Date_suf' with df.columns[0] + '_suffix'

Thanks, @iBeMeltin, for commenting my answer! You are right -- that would make the answer better. I am going to update it accordingly.
